# Garbage collection and GCHandle.Alloc

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

```
void Foo()
{
     System.Windows.Forms.Form f = new System.Windows.Forms.Form();
     f.Show();
}
```

To my understanding f holds the reference to the Form. But f is a local variable and it will go out of scope when the control leaves the curly braces. But the Form is still open. I tried calling GC.Collect(), but the Form is still open.

One more scenario.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.Enabled = true;
        t.Interval = 1000;
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
    }

    void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

In this scenario the t is never getting garbage collected. After a lot of research, I found Timer class is requesting GC not to collect using - GCHandle.Alloc when I set t.Enabled = true. Guys, this is a big source of memory leak. Unless I set t.Enabled = false, the whole Form will be leaked even after we close the Form.

In the first example code, I could not understand why the Form didn't get garbage collected even after I trigger a GC.Collect(). In reflector I saw ControlNativeWindow has been used in Form which internally uses GCHandle.Alloc. Is that a reason?. As a user of the .NET library, I always believed that when a reference goes not reachable, it will get a chance for garbage collection. Of-course garbage collection and the actual release from memory is un-deterministic. But my question here is - Is my understanding correct for both the examples? When there are objects that can live even after it goes not-reachable, then how will I track that to prevent memory leak?

Comment: Hardly a huge memory leak.. unless there are huge lifetime/performance issues you've not made us aware of. Besides, your event still has a subscriber does it not?

Comment: When a form is shown, one can actually obtain a list of opened forms via [`System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx). You can hardly say there is no reference to the forms.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead For a Form there might be a reference somewhere else, as Alvin Wong pointed out. For the timer example, a subscriber cannot prevent from garbage collection.

Comment: That made me think of another thing: Classes which implements `IDisposable` holds unmanaged resources, which you need to *explicitly* call `Dispose` to release them. Or else, there *is likely to be* a memory leak.

Comment: @AlvinWong You are correct. As a .NET library user, we cannot drill down to every object and see how they implemented internally. Like this Timer we don't know how many more .NET objects are there that requested GC to prolong collection. I'm going to assume all IDisposable must be Disposed else memory leak.

Comment: Ram, this is not always correct. You may have a class that implements IDisposable AND additionally has a finalizer ~MyClass() which is called by the framework to destroy the class even if nobody ever calls Dispose(). Dispose() is only required if you want to give the programmer the chance to destroy the object at the moment HE wants to. (e.g. free a large Bitmap at the moment he is done with it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Winforms keeps an internal table that maps handles to control instances.  That table ensures that a control (the form in your case) can never be garbage collected as long as the native window is alive.  It gets removed from that table when the window is destroyed, either by the user closing the form or your code disposing it.

The System.Timers.Timer is kept alive by a cookie that's referenced by the CLR.  The class is implemented with a System.Threading.Timer which has a constructor that takes a *state* object argument.  That *state* object is the cookie, the CLR keeps it referenced with the equivalent of GCHandle.Alloc().  Disabling the timer resets the cookie which allows the timer to be garbage collected.

These are natural and necessary ways that the framework prevents these objects from getting garbage collected too early.  You can only cause a leak by forgetting to disable the timer when the form is disposed.  Which in general is quite unhealthy, you don't want a timer to keep ticking when the form is dead.  Move the Dispose method from the Designer.cs file into the form code or override OnFormClosed() to disable the timer.

Comment: Thank you for explaining me the behavior. A form will be visible to the user and I can depend on the user to close and dispose it. For the timer, if I forget to dispose the timer, there will be resource leak in both managed and un-managed. For an average user this is confusing. Calling Dispose() seem to be mandatory for all IDisposable objects.

Comment: You have to stop the timer, that's all.  Not stopping it is a bug, not a resource leak.

Answer (score 1):

You have to manage lifetime of `Form` and `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` instances yourself. You need to call `Dispose` to mark end of their lifetime and `GC` will collect them afterwards. Closing a form calls `Dispose` internally. If your timer was placed on the form using designer then the timer will be disposed when the form is closed. This is achieved by designer generating the following code in the form constructor:

```
this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
```

and `Dispose` of the form is:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && (components != null))
    {
        components.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

So in reality there's no memory leak as long as you close your forms and not just hide them. But if you created your timer manually then you have to dispose it yourself when the form is closed.

On the other hand `System.Threading.Timer` will be garbage-collected if you don't have any references to it even if you didn't `Dispose` it.

Comment: I tried to upvote, but I got an error message in a popup saying An error has occurred - please retry your request. So I shall retry later.

Comment: I'm new to this forum. I need 15 reps to upvote. But give me some time, I will come back again here :)

Comment: It is not necessary to Dispose() each and every Timer. But you must stop all your Timer's in Form.OnClosed().