# System.Timers.Timer enabled and GarbageCollector

Tags: c#, .net, timer, garbage-collection

In my project i created  `System.Timers.Timer` object and the interval is set to 10 min.
For every 10 min I am getting elapsed event. In this event handler i am executing some code.

Before executing this code I am setting `Enabled` property equal to `false` because if the handler takes longer to execute than the next interval another thread executes the elapsed event.

Problem here is suddenly `Elapsed` event is stopped.

I have read some articles and suspecting that the moment enabled property set to false garbagecollector frees the timer object.

If it is right please tell me the solution.

Below is example code:

```
public class Timer1
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

    public static void Main()
    {
        // Create a timer with a ten second interval.
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

        // Set the Interval to 10min.
        aTimer.Interval = 600000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;

        Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit the program.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        aTimer.Enabled = false;

        // excutes some code

        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the link for that article? It sounds incorrect for me. What a reason for GC to collect still referenced object with property set to some value? This is very uncommon behavior of GC in .NET

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Please look at the below logs which are states that "when Enabled property set it to false its marked for GC,so it could free the resources held by the timer"

http://forums.codeguru.com/printthread.php?t=342524

http://kvarnhammar.blogspot.com/2008/12/systemwindowsformstimer-and-garbage.html

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617336/garbage-collection-and-gchandle-alloc

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216098/why-does-a-timer-keep-my-object-alive

Answer (score 3):

Since you have a field in your class pointing to your timer object, the GC will not collect the timer object.

But your code may raise exception, and this can prevent the `Enabled` property to become true again. To guard agianst this, you should use a `finally` block:

```
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    aTimer.Enabled = false;
    try
    {
        // excutes some code
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // log the exception and possibly rethrow it
        // Attention: never swallow exceptions!
    }
    finally
    {
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers i will try as you said.

Please look at the below logs which are states that "when Enabled property set it to false its marked for GC,so it could free the resources held by the timer"

http://forums.codeguru.com/printthread.php?t=342524

http://kvarnhammar.blogspot.com/2008/12/systemwindowsformstimer-and-garbage.html

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617336/garbage-collection-and-gchandle-alloc

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216098/why-does-a-timer-keep-my-object-alive

Comment: @user2080185 Those links are all talking about timer objects that **go out of scopt** but **not garbage collected**. But your situation is the reverse. Your timer **is in scope** and you are holding a referece to it. So GC never collects it, until you **stop the timer** and **give up the reference** to ther timer object. The cases in those post do not apply to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can set synchronization object, in that case the elapsed will happen only on the
owner thread of that object, with no concurrency.
A similar question is posted here:
[Do C# Timers elapse on a separate thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435876/do-c-sharp-timers-elapse-on-a-separate-thread)